# Cannot retarget the Windows SDK in Visual Studio 2022 with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I recently reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 because I reset my Windows install, but whenever I try to make a new empty C++ file it shows 470+ errors most with the codes E1696 and E0282.

Googling it says to just change the SDK my project uses, but doing it through the properties menu and clicking the arrow doesn't show anything (I tried typing in 10.0.22000.0 manually because that's the latest I have installed but it didn't help) and going to Project -> Retarget Solution doesn't show a dropdown to select an SDK version, and clicking ok does nothing. I tried repairing the install, uninstalling and installing again in the same and in a different location, tried manually shift deleting any mention of VS 2022 and installing it again and none of it worked. I'm completely clueless as to what I need to do. Anyone with the same problem?

**Additional info:**

Running Windows 11 22H2 build 22621 |
Windows CRT SDK is installed |
Visual Studio 2022 version is 17.7.4 |
Platform toolset is v143

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I explained that I have multiple Windows SDKs installed (to test if any of them will show up) and none of them will even with All selected under both config and platform

Comment: Errors starting with E are just intellisense. Do you get errors starting with C when compiling?

Comment: The code cannot compile at all. Trying to build the solution just shows 1 failed (the only project I have in it currently) and trying to run the code just shows that there were build errors

Comment: Did you install C++ workload after reset Windows?